# NodeJS - More Users Connections of WebSocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have programming one socket server on nodejs.
testing the server, only support 256 connections, how increase maximum connections?

Code:

```
  var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
  var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: config.Server[0] });
```

(config.Server[0] = 80(

Answer (score 0):

Each socket connection creates a file, each user of an OS has a limit to create files. Check ulimit of a user by which you are running your app.js. Try increasing this limit to support more connections. I have set this limit to infinite.
Following link may help you to check your ulimit and how to increase this limit.
[Increase ufile limit(ubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user)

Comment: Not sure about windowa, but http://blogs.technet.com/b/tristank/archive/2008/03/11/maxuserport-what-it-is-what-it-does-when-it-s-important.aspx this link may help you. :)